# Symmetries of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, symmetric-groups

I wonder who raise the concept that in a PDE system $\mathcal{L}$ with
$$ \mathcal{L}(u,x,y)=0$$

and $$\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{T}(u,x,y))=0$$
implies that operator $\mathcal{T}$ is a *symmetry* of $\mathcal{L}$.

I would appreciate it if the original paper could be mentioned.Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you and yeah you got it exactly right about the Lie symmertry, however the infinitesimal generator is just a particular case of the transformation  $\mathcal{T}$. What I need is a general expression, maybe the way I wrote is widely agreed as a typical expression (which means I could just use it without citation?). Thankyou for answering again

Comment: @DominikS Thank you. Yes the above is a general way. Nevertheless I need a paper in a more precise domain (or a textbook maybe?). Anyway Thank you again~